# What does "the future may hold..." mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> In meiotic chromosomal interactions, the danger is that negative
>   interactions may be passed on to future generations. The mutations
>   result in a variety of well-known conditions. **The future may hold more
>   or fewer, and it is anybody's guess.**
>   A. Epistasis
>   B. Multiple
>   alleles... etc.

What does the bold sentence mean in this context? I have found the meaning of one part of a sentence only: https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&hs=pEi&q=it+is+anybody%27s+guess&oq=it+is+anybody%27s+guess&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l4.16718.16718.0.17851.1.1.0.0.0.0.98.98.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.96.gEzotNrmox4
Does it mean that diseases that are passed on may be more or less serious and it is difficult to determine whether they will be inherited or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence means that, in the future, there may be more or less mutations than at present and that there is no way to know which will happen.

"It is anybody's guess" is a way of saying "we have no clue".

Comment: And another way to say "we have no clue" is "nobody knows for sure"